# Pass an array of numbers into a method that's overloaded

Tags: java, beginner, homework

I'm doing my homework and it says to write a test program that prompts the user to enter ten double values, invokes this method, and displays the average value.

I was able to get this program working with an overloaded method... but I'm curious to hear your feedback on where I can improve and what I'm not understanding 100%. Please feel free to review this and let me know your constructive feedback as to my code and where you think I can do better.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PP68 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {//start main

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //new object of scanner type

        double avg =0, total =0;

        double[] average = new double[10];      //double array


        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){             //enter 10 numbers to average
            System.out.print("Enter a number to average.");
            average[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < average.length; j++) {
            total = total + average[j];
            avg = total / average.length;
        }
        System.out.println("The average of your arrays numbers is: " + avg);

    }//end main

    public static int average(int[] array){ //1st method
        int total =0;
        int avg = total / array.length;
        return avg;

    }//end 1st method
    public static double average(double[] array) {//Second method - overloaded
        double total = 0;
        double avg = total / array.length;
        return avg;

    }//end 2nd method

}
```

---

New code follows below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PP68v2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 1 to average an INT or hit 2 to average a DOUBLE");
    int entry = input.nextInt();

        if (entry == 2) {                                  //choose double and call double method
            double[] array = new double[10];
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                    System.out.println("Enter a number to average.");
                    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
                }
                System.out.println("The average of your arrays numbers is: " + average(array));

        } else if (entry == 1) {                           //choose int and call int method
            int[] array = new int[10];
                for(int b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter a number to average.");
                    array[b] = input.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println("The average of your arrays numbers is: " + average(array));
        }

    }

    public static int average(int[] array){
        int total =0;
        int avg1 = 0;
            for(int b=0; b < 10; b++) {
                total = total + array[b];
                avg1 = total / 10;
            }
        return avg1;

    }

    public static double average(double[] array) {
        double total = 0;
        double avg = 0;
            for(int i =0; i < 10; i++) {
                total =  total + array[i];
                avg = total / array.length;
            }
        return avg;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The code produces the right output, which is good.  It has some problems, though.

#### The `average()` functions

As @ChrisW points out, the two `average()` functions you defined are not being used.  Since your inputs are `double`s, you only need one of them: the `double average(double[] array)` function.

The `average()` functions are currently buggy:

- `total = 0`, so of course they will each always return 0.  Copy the summation code from `main()` to fix that.
- The `int` version uses integer arithmetic, so division rounds the result to an integer (towards 0).  In general, the average of a set of integers is not an integer.  You should use `double` to store the total, even in the integer version.  (You did it correctly in `main()`.)

In case you're wondering, if you want to be able to handle integral and floating-point input arrays, you do need to write out both the `int[]` and `double[]` versions explicitly.

#### `main()`

If you open a `Scanner`, it's good etiquette to close it.  The idiom for doing that since Java 7 is to use a try-with-resources block:

```
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    …
}
```

Avoid declaring and defining variables `avg` and `total` until you need them.

The `average` array is poorly named.  It's an array of ten user input numbers, not an array of ten averages.

You hard-coded `10` twice.  The first for-loop should be more like the second, which uses `average.length`.

The average only needs to be computed once, not ten times.  Pull the division operation out of the loop.

Of all the comments in the class, the only one worth keeping is `// enter 10 numbers to average`.  All of the others are redundant noise.

Comment: Thanks. I've been working on a revised version and I'd like to post that and reply to some of your comments. Sadly, I'm still having trouble with the syntax.

Comment: @Pivo If the syntax you are having trouble with is calling a method with an array as a parameter, I tried https://www.google.com/search?q=java+call+method+array+parameter as a Google query and it found http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/array-param.html which you might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote the `average` method but you're not calling it.

The `average` method need not be overloaded because the problem doesn't ask for a version of it which works with `int` arrays (so you can delete the version which works with `int` arrays).

The `average` method is setting `double total = 0;` but is then not summing the elements in the array (you're currently doing that, calculating the total, in your second `for` loop inside main: instead that `for` loop should be moved into the body of your `average` method, and your `main` should call that `average` method instead of running that `for` loop).

In `main` the array is named `average`: it should probably be renamed to `input` or something like that.

Comment: Ew, that's a great point. How would I make use of the int average method? As this is the first overloaded method I'm trying to write, I'm a bit confused on that.

Comment: To invoke the `int average` method you would need to pass an array of type `int[]` as a parameter. Currently you only create one array in `main`, and that array is of type `double[]`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll repost once I've taken into account your help.